# $(2x+y)\frac{dy}{dx} + x = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve:
>   $(2x+y)\frac{dy}{dx} + x = 0$ .

Only solving seperable equations and use of an integrating factor have been covered so far, and I can't see how to get it into a form such that it is solvable by these methods.

Comment: It's easy to notice one important thing about this differential equation, it's homogeneous!
$$\left(2x + y\right) \mathrm dy = - x\ \mathrm dx$$
What does that mean? The maximum power on both sides is 1. 
This is a degree 1 order 1 homogeneous diff. eq. How does this fact help us? Try putting $y = vx$ and see the mathemagic =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try  $y = vx $

$\implies   y' = v'x + v$

The equation becomes
$$(2x+vx)(v'x+v) + x = 0 \\ (2+v)(v'x+v)+1 = 0$$

which is separable

Answer (score -4):

That is :
$(x+y)dy + xdx=0$

Which is
$xdy + ydy + xdx = 0$

Integrate all parts:
$xy + \frac{y^2+x^2}{2}=c$

Comment: The confusing part is $\displaystyle \int x\ \mathrm dy$. Why do you assume that $x$ is a constant with respect to $y$ ?

Comment: Differentiating that result gives $y + x dy/dx + y dy/dx + x = 0$ which is not the original equation.

Comment: Dear @fodon, it is important to know that downvotes are just the community's way of saying that your answer just isn't right. You've made a fairly common mistake though and hopefully you've learnt why. We all appreciate your answer. Thank you =)